# Get data from HTTP Header Variable in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am setting up an authentification scheme, type **HTTP Header Variable**

[image]

The informations sent by the HTTP query are: ID_USER, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, EMAIL and PROFIL

Actually I get the ID_USER in APEX using the bind variable APP_USER or using the V function V('APP_USER')

My question is how to get the other informations like LAST and FIRST NAME ?

I am on APEX 4.2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

I use the **owa_util.get_cgi_env** function to get the informations I want